# failed to open stream after PHP upgrade to 7.3

Tags: smarty, php7

Started getting this error on some Civi pages after upgrading PHP to 7.3 on  server running php-fpm and nginx.

Works fine after restarting php-fpm but need to restart every morning to get around with these issue. Has anyone come across this issue?

```
Warning: include(/var/sites/drupalsite/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB//%%30/307/307241E0%%Extensions.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 1911 of /var/www/drupal759civi5192/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php).
```

Answer (score 1):

May be a stupid question but have you purged caches / cache folders entirely? e.g. Clear the templates_c folder?

Comment: Yes we did that too.. unless we restart php-fpm it keeps throwing error